# How to parse multidimensional json array in Volley?

Tags: android, arrays, json, android-volley

I am returning a json_encoded array in PHP to my Android client. I first gather data from the server and enter it into an array called "data":

```
$data[] = array('name'=>$name, 'distance'=>(int)$distance, 'city'=>$city, 'state'=>$state, 'interest'=>$interest, 'avatar'=>$avatar);
```

Then, I place that array into another array to get a count variable, which is just an increment in my for loop. Looks like this:

```
$response = array('data'=>$data, 'count'=>$count);
```

On the Android side, I retrieve this with:

```
StringRequest searchPostRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, searchURL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {
                    mPlayerSuccess.start();
                    Log.d(TAG, "Complete Response: "+response);
                    JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response);
                    /*
                     *GET THE COMPLETE JSON ARRAY FROM SERVER
                     * ARRAY NAME IS "data"
                     * Strings are name, distance, city, state, interest, avatar
                     */
                    JSONArray array = object.getJSONArray("data");
                    for(int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = array.getJSONObject(i);
                        String name = jsonObject.getString("name");
                        int distance = jsonObject.getInt("distance");
                        String city = jsonObject.getString("city");
                        String state = jsonObject.getString("state");
                        String interest = jsonObject.getString("interest");
                        String avatar = jsonObject.getString("avatar");
                        String formatted_avatar = avatar.replace("\\", "");
                        int count = jsonObject.getInt("count");

                        Log.d(TAG, "Name Returned: "+name);
                        Log.d(TAG, "Distance Returned: "+distance);
                        Log.d(TAG, "City Returned: "+city);
                        Log.d(TAG, "State Returned: "+state);
                        Log.d(TAG, "Interest Returned: "+interest);
                        Log.d(TAG, "Avatar Returned: "+formatted_avatar);
                        Log.d(TAG, "Count: "+count);
```

This returns (in my Log):

```
D/MainActivity: Complete Response: {"data":[{"name":"lgill10","distance":296,"city":"Clinton","state":"IL","interest":"3D printing","avatar":"..\/users\/lgill10\/uploads\/dj-franklin.jpg"},{"name":"lgill9","distance":316,"city":"Bloomington","state":"IL","interest":"3D printing","avatar":"css\/images\/user_default\/default_avatar.png"},{"name":"testuser2","distance":14,"city":"Jonesboro","state":"AR","interest":"3D printing","avatar":"css\/images\/user_default\/default_avatar.png"}],"count":3}
```

However, I am getting "No Value for count," which causes all of the 'Log.d' messages to not show up.

I also tried to extract the count with:

```
JSONArray count_array = object.getJSONArray("count");
JSONObject countObject = count_array.getJSONObject(0);
int count = countObject.getInt("count");
```

But then it catches the Exception and tells me:

```
Value 3 at count of type java.lang.Integer cannot be converted to JSONArray
```

It is returning the correct count (3), but I do not know how to properly extract it from the multidimensional array.

How can I get the count value? I feel like this is a minor syntax issue, I just don't know how to rectify it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wish I would have thought of this before asking, but it just dawned on me. Since the count variable is actually the array length, I accessed it with:

```
int count = array.length();
Log.d(TAG, "Count: "+count);
```

which returns:

```
Count: 3
```